# 401 error using Alamofire and swift when trying to connect to my server

Tags: swift, ios7, alamofire

Ok so I am trying to download a json file as a string and parse it out latter. But I have to download it from my webpage first. This webpage needs a username and password to get to it. This has been giving me a 401 error so its not sending the username or password. How can I add the username and password to the request?

```
 print("Downloading the json file")
    let plainString = "\(myUserName):\(myPassword)" as NSString
    let plainData = plainString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let base64String = plainData?.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))

    Alamofire.Manager.sharedInstance.session.configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = ["Authorization": "Basic " + base64String!]

    Alamofire.request(.GET, promoUrl)
        .response {(request, response, _, error) in
            print(response)
    }
```

This is the result from it

```
Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7fe103818790> { URL: http://xxxapi/1.0/promotions } { status code: 401, headers {
"Cache-Control" = "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate";
Connection = "keep-alive";
"Content-Length" = 186;
"Content-Type" = "application/json;charset=UTF-8";
Date = "Thu, 12 May 2016 01:36:33 GMT";
Expires = 0;
Pragma = "no-cache";
Server = "Apache-Coyote/1.1";
"Www-Authenticate" = "Basic realm=\"Realm\"";
"X-Content-Type-Options" = nosniff;
"X-Frame-Options" = DENY;
"X-XSS-Protection" = "1; mode=block";
```

Thank you very much for any help with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi every one so after working on it a bit more i got it to work. I got rid of all the stuff on top and went simple. It worked better and is easier to do

here is the working code for anyone who wants it

```
    Alamofire.request(.GET, promoUrl, parameters: [myUserName:myPassword])
        .authenticate(user: myUserName, password: myPassword)
        .response {(request, response, data, error) in
            print(response)


    }
```

The key difference is this

```
parameters: [myUserName:myPassword]
```

This loads my password and username into the url. It may not be the best way of doing this but it works for my needs for now